# What do I need for this to connect to the water line it’s for my refrigerator water/ice maker

Tags: water, refrigerator, ice-maker

[image] I just bought a new refrigerator and they installed it but wouldn’t hook up the ice maker to my water line. I’m not sure what I need to hook it up. Blue hose comes from the refrigerator and the other end is the water line.

Answer (score 1):

I can't *quite* tell for sure from the picture, which is a bit small and poorly lit, but it appears that simply removing the male-to-male coupling on the end of the refrigerator line might allow it to connect. Or it might be slightly different sizes and you'll need an adapter. I brightened it up a bit, and they look *close* to the same size. You could also use a female to female coupling there, but given the choice of no extra joints or two extra joints, I'll pick none, as there are fewer places to leak.

[image: detail from image in question]